# Reading the name of the two columns from two radiobuttons and put their vectors in one dataframe in R Shiny

Tags: shiny

I have a set of built-in data. The goal is to read in the names of two columns from two RadioButtons and then, making a DataFrame from the chosen columns. I make this reproducible example here.

If you run the

```
 output$mytable = renderDataTable(vector1)
```

or

```
 output$mytable = renderDataTable(vector2)
```

separately, you'll find each one of observeEvents is working properly but I'm stuck and I can't put those columns together.

P.S.1. I know the last two lines will give an error because there is no `vector1` and `vector2` at first. Therefore, I put # to make them comments.

P.S.2. I need to use the resultant data frame in another place. That's why I'm insisting on forming one data frame.

```
library(shiny)

vchoices <- 1:ncol(mtcars)
names(vchoices) <- names(mtcars)

runApp(list(
  ui = basicPage(
    h2('The mtcars data'),
    radioButtons(
      "column1",
      "select columns",
      choices = vchoices,
      inline = T
    ),
    radioButtons(
      "column2",
      "select columns",
      choices = vchoices,
      inline = T
    ),
    dataTableOutput('mytable')
  ),

  server = function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$column1, {
      cols1 <- as.numeric(input$column1)
      vector1 <- data.frame(mtcars[, cols1])
      names(vector1) <- c("Firstcolumn")
      #output$mytable = renderDataTable(vector1)
    })

    observeEvent(input$column2, {
      cols2 <- as.numeric(input$column2)
      vector2 <- data.frame(mtcars[, cols2])
      names(vector2) <- c("Firstcolumn")
      #output$mytable = renderDataTable(vector2)
    })
    #z <- cbind(vector1, vector2)
    #output$mytable = renderDataTable(z)
    }
 ))
```

Comment: Why don't you just write `output$mytable <- renderDataTable(mtcars[,c(as.numeric(input$column1),as.numeric(input$column2))])`?

Comment: @HubertL I think you are right. I could use the same structure and form a data frame. Thanks

Comment: I tried to write `z = mtcars[,c(as.numeric(input$column1),as.numeric(input$column2))]
    output$mytable = renderDataTable(z)` but it is giving an error and the operation needs and active reactive environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it in 2 steps, you can use `reactive`:

```
z <- reactive(mtcars[,c(as.numeric(input$column1),as.numeric(input$column2‌​))] )

output$mytable = renderDataTable(z()) # Notice the parenthesis after z
```

Comment: Accurate! Thank you. I don't have reputation but I voted for your answer.